# Regex pattern with grep for expression2 AFTER expression1

Tags: regex, ubuntu, grep

I am trying to find which of a bunch of HTML files have a heading with the word Agent with the name of a particular agent anywhere after that heading.

So typically something like

```
<h3>Agent</h3>
<p>Blah blah blah </p>
<p>Their agent is XYZ Corp.</p>
```

should be found

But I cant guarantee any regularity on markup or content between the heading and the instance of XYZ Corp. So in something like DOS I might search for 'Agent*XYZ' meaning

```
-match the string 'Agent'
-followed by anything
-followed by the string 'XYZ'
```

How do I write that in grep on Ubuntu?
I have tried

```
grep -lc 'Agent*XYZ' *.html
grep -lc 'Agent.*?XYZ' *.html
```

both without success. I can find the pattern manually in more than one of the files, so I know it exists.

TIA

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question to me. Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Make the grep case insensitive and remove non greedy `?`:

```
grep -ilc 'Agent.*XYZ' *.html
#   __^       __^^
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference

Comment: @FeargalHogan:Have edited the answer, does it work now?

Comment: Yes - some - but it doesn't find 'Agent.*XYZ Corp' which I was expecting it to

Comment: @FeargalHogan: It works for me. How do you see that doesn't work? Try with `-i` option alone: `grep -i 'Agent.*XYZ' *.html`, you'll see the lines that matche.